# How to scroll to a particular index in collection view in swift 4?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift4, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewdelegate

I have searched various links related to this question but unable to solve this issue that's why I am posting this question. I have a `collectionView`. In a particular cell I have many views like **UserProfileView**, **ProductView**, **CommentBoxView** etc. In **CommentBoxView** there is a **textView** where the user can type and then post the comment. After posting the comment I want to scroll that particular cell, from which cell user have posted the comment. I know that I have to use `self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: indexNumber, section:       sectionNumber), at: .right, animated: false)`

Here is code,

```
func customCell(_ cell: UICollectionViewCell, didPressButton: UIButton, indexPathRow: Int, commentPost: String, commentatorImage: UIImageView, commentatorName: UILabel, comments: UITextView) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0, execute: {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        self.postComment(commentatorImage: commentatorImage, commentatorName: commentatorName, comments: comments) })
}
```

But my question are:

1. Where I have to write this code? In view did appear? or in the
   comment post function where the success is true?
2. How can I pass indexNumber and sectionNumber to

   `self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: indexNumber,    section:sectionNumber)`

Please anyone help me regarding this matter. Thanks

Comment: Can you use another class for add the comment??

Comment: i am using a function for add the comment. where a api is called. if necessary i can use another class.

Comment: where are you calling your post comment method? From a button's action may be?

Comment: i have used custom delegate

Comment: Can you show that code?

Comment: You should call this method right after your call of collectionView.reloadData()

Comment: func customCell(_ cell: UICollectionViewCell, didPressButton: UIButton, indexPathRow: Int, commentPost: String, commentatorImage: UIImageView, commentatorName: UILabel, comments: UITextView) {
       
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0, execute: {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
            self.postComment(commentatorImage: commentatorImage, commentatorName: commentatorName, comments: comments)
            
        })

Comment: @najam okay sir and how can i pass the indexNumber and sectionNumber

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of the life cycle method or even after your reload data call. Something like this,

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() 
{
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 12, section: 0)
    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: [.centeredVertically,   .centeredHorizontally], animated: true)
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 12, section: 0) sir item 12 means?

Comment: Item 12 is your cell number where you want to scroll in section 0

Comment: Just like UITableView where we use indexPath.row method, here in collectionView we prefer using IndexPath.Item because collectionView can be Vertical or Horizontal.

Comment: that means i have to pass IndexPath.Item in  IndexPath(item: 12, section: 0) . right sir?

Comment: No no, you are creating IndexPath, all you have to do is just find correct position of your comment, let's say you have an array of comments and its size is 12 now a new comment posted by user, what will be the size of array now ???? 12+1 = 13 right ??? and because array has 0 index so position will be 12 ??? Okay. 
Simple pass (commentsArray.length -1) as your position

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176035/discussion-between-najam-and-gorib-developer).

Comment: i will ping you after some time sir. i am in a middle of something

Answer (score 0):

As per the custom delegate method you have shown:

```
func customCell(_ cell: UICollectionViewCell, didPressButton: UIButton, indexPathRow: Int, commentPost: String, commentatorImage: UIImageView, commentatorName: UILabel, comments: UITextView) { 
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0, execute: { 
        self.collectionView.reloadData() 
        self.postComment(commentatorImage: commentatorImage, commentatorName: commentatorName, comments: comments) 
    })
```

I believe you are passing the `cell` from your cell class to controller. So inside your custom delegate method, you can get the indexPath like below way:

```
let indexPath = yourCollectionView.indexPath(for: yourCollectionCell)
```

Now you can scroll to this indexPath. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: yes i am getting that like this   let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)

Comment: that means in scroll to item i have to pass this indexPath? right sir?

Comment: Exactly brother. Sir bolar kono dorkar nei bhai! <3 Solve hole ekta upvote ar mark selected koris.

Comment: Thanks a lot bhai \m/

Comment: We are bengalis. :) But mu odiya bhi janichi tike tike. :)

Comment: @iPeter bhai achis naki?

Comment: Hmm! Always. :)

Comment: @iPeter:bhai achis?

Comment: Hmm Bol. @GoribDeveloper

Comment: ekta problem e atke gechilam.tai ping korechilam.. thik ache.. solve hy gache